# UIButton tag value doesn't pass in prepareForSegue method in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

The feed of my app is managed by a UITableViewController where I set custom cells that are instances of a UITableViewCell sub class.

One property of that sub class is a UIButton called flameRelation:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton* flameRelation;
```

I am creating a dynamic segue to a detail view controller depending on the class of the sender.  If the sender is the cell itself, I pass a given set of data to my detail view controller.  If the sender is the flameRelation button, I pass another.

To achieve this, I am looking at the following 2-step approach:

1) Since I need to know the indexpath.row of the cell where the FlameRelation button was pressed, I set the tag of that button in the UITableView method that sets each cell of my feed as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Set a bunch of things before setting UIButton flameRelation tag

   [cell.flameRelation setTag:indexPath.row];
```

And I am printing the tag which allows me to check that the tag is being set when I scroll down my feed after launching my build (I see the numbers incrementing as I scroll down, as expected).

```
NSLog(@"The button tag for this cell is set to %ld",(long)[cell.flameRelation tag]);
```

2) In the prepareForSegue method that allows the user to transition to the detail view controller with the relevant information, I test the class of the sender first.  If the class of the sender is UIButton, I attempt to pass the right information to the detail view controller by setting the value of the indexpath to the value of the tag:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FlameDetail"]) {
    FlameDetailViewController* flameDetailController = (FlameDetailViewController*) segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[FlameCellTableViewCell class]])
    {
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    NSLog(@"The indexPath is: %@", indexPath);

    flameDetailController.flame = [self.feed flameAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"class for object sender: %@", NSStringFromClass([sender class]));
    }


    else if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"The button tag is set to %ld",(long)[sender tag]);
        NSIndexPath* indexPath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
        NSLog(@"The indexPath from UIButton is: %@", indexPath);

        flameDetailController.flame = [self.feed flameAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"The value of indexPath.row is %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

        NSLog(@"class for object sender: %@", NSStringFromClass([sender class]));
        flameDetailController.findOutView.hidden = NO;
        [flameDetailController.flameAction setTitle:@"CHAT NOW" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"Yes, the sender is UIButton");
        NSLog(@"The title of flameAction is set to %@", flameDetailController.flameAction.titleLabel.text);
    }
}
```

Everything works well if I tap on the cell itself, but if I tap on the flameRelation button, I see in my logs that the getter on tag returns 0.  Which obviously doesn't transfer the proper information to my target view controller.

Thanks!

Comment: In prepareForSegue, does the UIButton conditional statement execute? If you put a breakpoint there, does sender.tag have a value?

Comment: Are you saying statement `The indexPath from UIButton is: ` always prints 0?

Comment: Hi @remus and Abhinav:  Yes, [sender tag] is always set to 0.  The UIButton conditional statement execute and when I print the value of the tag, I see 0.  Which is not normal.

Comment: Can you try setting a different property? Maybe subclass UIButton and create your own @property?

Answer (score 0):

First of all why you are converting your tag value to `indexPath` and then getting your model data with the row number?

**Your code:**

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
flameDetailController.flame = [self.feed flameAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**Try this instead:**

```
flameDetailController.flame = [self.feed flameAtIndex:sender.tag];
```

I do not see a reason why this approach would not work. If it does not you need to share more code/details.

However, I would want to suggest another alternate (no so great though):

```
UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
```

Comment: Abhinav:  It looks like we are on the way.  Your first recommendation doesn't work (sender.tag creates an error and the tag still print 0 anyway).  The second is better (tag no longer at 0) but the properties that I want to pass are null.  See: [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjs99wv9wmg3t2o/Screenshot%202015-10-02%2010.57.24.png).  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Abhinav, @remus:  Thanks for your help.  It made me think more about solutions and I found it.  Because of the view controller life cycle, I called the view from the detail controller and then set outlets.  I just call the view with `[segue.destinationViewController view];`  Yeah!